# Integrating AWS Lambda and HTTP endpoint together in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Let's say I have a service to allow people to upload photos. I store these photos in S3, and to make it efficient, I use Cloudfront. In order to upload these photos to S3, I was recommended to use Lambdas with API Gateway. However, I'd also like to send this request to a custom HTTP endpoint as well, and return that in the response from the Gateway. So my ideal process is:

1. User submits upload photo
2. Photo gets sent to API Gateway
3. API Gateway calls Lambda to store photo in S3 and also forwards the request to custom backend API
4. Backend sends back some info
5. API Gateway sends back this info to client

Is this possible? From the [integrations doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations.html), it seems like I can only do Lambdas or HTTP custom endpoint. Not sure how to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow should be like this

- Create a lambda endpoint to create signedUrl and return to frontend for s3 upload
- Once you have the signed URL upload the pic to the signed URL from the frontend
- Once the operation is successful either you can send a request to the lambda from the frontend or a event on the s3 bucket to do further processing